# Is there a way to know whether a fleet has already attacked this turn?

Tags: endless-space, endless-space-disharmony

I had a system with two of my fleets and one enemy fleet. One of my fleets attacked and destroyed the enemy fleet, but I forgot which - and now I want to move the fleet that has not already attacked to another system, to attack another enemy fleet there.

Is there any way to tell which fleet has already attacked this round, without having an enemy fleet present?

Comment: I feel like there should be a tooltip when you hover over the attack button that says why you can't attack if it's grayed out. It might just say there're no ships around, but maybe check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DCShannon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/108003/dcshannon) gave me a hint to look in the tooltip appearing when I hover over the attack button, and indeed, if the fleet is able to attack it will be:

[image: "Cannot attack: there are no enemy fleets in this star system"]

While if the fleet has already attacked, it will be:

[image: "Cannot attack: your fleet has no ships suitable for an attack"]